# How to store multiple select option in MySql for easy searching

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I am uncertain of the best way to store multiple select options into mysql. Initially, I created a comma separated list of selected values.  I have read that this is bad programming practice and also had a difficult time trying to figure out how to search the three columns in my db with the comma separated varchar value (eg: 1,5,17).  It seems the best practice would be to create a 3rd table that would insert 3 records for the example above.  This table would be linked via an id.

Example:
Table 1 (age levels)has fields id & age level (baby,teenager,adult)
Table 2 has classes id & class name
Table 3 is to store the multiple select options of WHO can attend each class. I guess the fields would be id & classID & ageLevelID

My questions are as follows:
1. how do I efficiently insert this data into table 2 and table 3?
2. how do I pull it all together to search for a person who is looking for a class that allows for just babies and teenagers, for example?

Relating 2 tables is easy, relating 3 tables is a conceptual struggle. Also, am I correct that it is asking for trouble to store comma delimited values in one field? Thank you.

Comment: welcome to the joys of **JOIN**

Comment: I understand the concept of join...my question is more with my NOT using 2 tables and a comma delimited multiple selection and instead using a 3rd table.  Would you agree with my method of handling this multiple selection issue?  Will I need 2 sql statements to populate table 2 and 3 or can it be done with one sql statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table agelevel  (ageid (unique), agelevel)

Table classes  (classid (unique), classname)

Table classesinfo  (classid, fieldname,fieldvalue)

With that you could have any 'fieldname' such as agelevel, detailed description, hours, etc and then the value of that field in fieldvalue.  This allows your classes to any an infinite number variables attached to a single classid.

Comment: Shouldn't fieldname be ageID which would bring in ageLevel?  I am specifically looking for the SQL that would be used if someone offered a class that allowed 2 ageLevels, for instance. Can the data be INSERTED into the db with only one SQL statement?  Also, when I need to search for classes that are for adults only, how would I do this?  Bringing in the 3rd table is giving me some trouble.

Comment: Yes fieldname should have been ageid in my above example.  Once you get your tables created setup some classes with different agelevel you can post more details so we can give you an accurate answer